# thatched-roof huts - wrong position of words?

Tags: adjective-phrases

There is correct pattern to say complex adjectives: adjcective+noun+ed. For example: green-eyed, tall-stalked. But in my book I have stumbled onto word "thatched-roof" with words other way around. Can you explain to me why? The text is:

> They were barefoot, wore hardly any clothes, and some wore bones through their noses. Dr. Howlett explained that they lived nearby in a village of **thatched-roof** huts, and the missionaries were learning their language and telling them about Christ.

Comment: Thatched-roof is the adjective, hut is the noun.

Comment: Are you asking why  "green-**eyed**" and "tall-**stalked**" are correct but not "thatch-**roofed**". Is it that ZWA? The position of the adjective (thatched) in the noun phrase "thatched-roof hut" is correct.

Comment: @Mari-Lou.. Ahh, I see.

Answer (score 1):

In the example "green-eyed" you are combining adjectives "green" and "eyed".

However the adjective in "thatched roof" is "thatched" (the word "thatch" is normally a noun) and it is describing the noun "roof".

A "thatched roof" is a noun phrase and it is being used attributively to describe the noun "hut".

I feel that "thatched-roofed huts" would be possible in this context too.